# How i can use custom listview in react-native-google-places-autocomplete?

Tags: react-native, react-google-autocomplete

I have two autocompleteinputs but i want them to use same listview to look nicer. The app i am developing looks like lyft in lyft they use two text inputs in destination selection screen. How i can create autocompleteinput with custom list view?

I have readed the react-native-google-places-autocomplete documents. But didn't manage to find good solution.